# emacs ediff-revision for Hg complains about Wrong number of arguments

Tags: emacs, mercurial, emacs-ediff

Trying to get ediff-revision working on hg (mercurial-1.8.4) repo using Emacs v23.2 (9.0) on OS X Lion.  I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177304/how-do-you-get-ediff-hg-working-in-emacs-23-2-for-mac) for the 1st part of my problem but now I'm getting this from Emacs ediff-revision:

*M-x ediff-revision
Compare revisions for file (default .hgtags): ~/myrepo.hg/.hgtags
Revision 1 to compare (default .hgtags's latest revision): 
Revision 2 to compare (default .hgtags's current state):*

and I get the following response:

```
Checking out /Users/username/repo.hg/.hgtags.~tip~...
apply: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (file &optional editable rev) "Retrieve a revision of FILE.
EDITABLE is ignored.
```

Comment: Try setting the variable `debug-on-error` to true. When the error happens, a buffer called `*Backtrace*` should be shown - add the contents of this buffer to your question.

Comment: Also, load libraries `ediff.el` and `ediff-util.el` before provoking the error.  That will give you more and better information in `*Backtrace*`, because it will refer to source code instead of byte-compiled code.  This is typically a good idea whenever you intend to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using an old emacs/vc/vc-hg version.  Simply upgrading is probably the easiest solution.

I had a similar problem, which I could solve bit by bit by improving small settings and even made a patch. It never really solved all. Until I upgrade to a recent emacs (and support file); I use the *Aquamacs* distribution now, which works great on the Mac. (Although it's keybindings are more mac the traditional-emacs)